# Java: Open New Window Instead of New Tab

Tags: java, url, window, uri

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Java’s Desktop library launch a URL in a new Browser Tab or Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706668/can-javas-desktop-library-launch-a-url-in-a-new-browser-tab-or-window)

When I run this code in Java it opens a new tab.

```
String url = "www.google.ca";
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI.create(url));
```

I am using google Chrome.  Is there a way to open it in a new window instead of a new tab?

Comment: What makes your web page target ***so special*** that it deserves its own browser window?  Note that `"www.google.ca"` is not a valid `URL`, which suggests you are making up code rather than copy/pasting it.

Comment: Canada will be disappointed to find out they no longer have [Google](http://www.google.ca).

Comment: @Perception your name says it all ;-}