# opening multiple sites in IE using java program

Tags: java, eclipse

**i want to open multiple websites in IE using java program.**

here is the code 
the **websites** are fetched from txt file

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        StringTokenizer webLink = new StringTokenizer(line,";");
        while(webLink.hasMoreTokens())
            {   
                    String webPathString = webLink.nextToken();
                    System.out.println(webPathString);
                    Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop(); 
                    desktop.browse(new URI(webPathString));
            }
    }
```

problem is only last site is getting opened in a browser insted of all.

Comment: _Please provide data of your text file._

Comment: have you tried introducing sleep()s? have you tried from multiple threads?

Comment: Note that your current code will open the URL in the user's preferred browser. *This is a good thing*, but I just wanted to point out it won't always be IE.

Comment: Have you confirmed that this code is actually run more than once (i.e. that while loop happens the expected amount of times)?

Comment: Two consecutive calls to `desktop.browse` will work as expected, so the issue has to be related to how you obtain that list of URLs. There's not enough info in your question to help you there, so I'm voting to close.

Answer (score -1):

desktop.browse will open all links in a current window only

For more details check the below discussion

[Can Java's Desktop library launch a URL in a new Browser Tab or Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706668/can-javas-desktop-library-launch-a-url-in-a-new-browser-tab-or-window)

Comment: Not true on my system, at least. Two separate IE instances were opened containing the URLs I requested.